# Generalizing fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is is possible to generalize the fundamental theorem of algebra to allow for any function $f(x)$ that is entire in the complex plane (or for polynomials of infinite order)?

I am interested in the following equation:

$$f(x) = 0$$

How many roots in the complex plane does this have?  If $f(x)$ is entire, then can I represent it as a convergent series in $x$ like this:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n = 0$$

Can I then view $f(x)$ as a polynomial of (countably) infinite order?  So then can I use the standard fundamental theorem of algebra to say this has a countably infinite number of roots in the complex plane?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27546/zeroes-of-holomorphic-function

Comment: How many roots has $e^x$?

Comment: @quid how about an infinite number of them, all at $x=-\infty$? :D

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity for you to look again at the *proof(s)* of the fundamental theorem of algebra, and see why they do not work for non-polynomials.

Comment: @QuantumDot $\;x=-\infty\;$ is *not* a complex number , so that doesn't work. Perhaps you could some some kind of generalization to the complex plane *union the point* $\;-\infty\;$ , but maybe some things would get weird there...